# precompile jsps into classes for Jetty8 using ant

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

We are using jspc ant task to pre-compile JSP files into classes/(then package into war)

Now we are switching to Jetty 8. According to the doc, there exists a maven plugin to do [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP). Do we have ant task to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its best if you use the JSP libs that comes with the jetty distribution.

Here's an example, using jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="AntExample1" default="war">

    <property name="jetty.home" value="${user.home}/code/intalio/distros/jetty-distribution-8.1.5.v20120716" />

    <path id="compile.jspc">
        <fileset dir="${jetty.home}">
            <include name="lib/servlet-api-*.jar" />
            <include name="lib/jsp/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <path id="compile.classpath">
        <fileset dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <path refid="compile.jspc" />
    </path>

    <target name="jspc" depends="compile">
        <taskdef classname="org.apache.jasper.JspC" name="jasper2" classpathref="compile.jspc" />
        <jasper2 validateXml="false"
            uriroot="WebContent"
            addWebXmlMappings="true"
            webXmlFragment="WebContent/WEB-INF/generated_web.xml"
            compilerSourceVM="1.6"
            compilerTargetVM="1.6"
            outputDir="build/gen-src"
            verbose="9" />
    </target>

    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
        <mkdir dir="build/gen-src" />
        <mkdir dir="dist" />
        <copy todir="build/gen-src">
            <fileset dir="src" includes="**/*.java" />
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="build/gen-src">
            <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="jspc">
        <war destfile="dist/AntExample.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent" />
        <classes dir="build/classes" />
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

</project>
```

**Update: April 8, 2013**

Pushed an example project with this build to github.

https://github.com/jetty-project/jetty-example-jspc-ant

Comment: @ joakime  : My 100 point bounty vanished without a trace. Hopefully this 200 point bounty will compensate that :)

Comment: @Jayan the bounty didn't vanish, it expired on monday. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Jasper has jspc; the linked page has ant code for calling it.](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/jasper/JspC.html)

Answer (score 0):

From your first sentence you are apparently already using an ant task to pre-compile the jsp files...so using jetty-8 doesn't mean you have to change that process at all, you will still just pre-compile as you have been, building your war file as you have been and then just deploy into jetty-8.  You will need to add jsp to the OPTIONS in the start.ini to get the jsp engine into the server classloader.