# Loading jsps with jetty that are precompiled still requires jdk?

Tags: jsp, jetty, precompile

I'm trying to use jetty with a JRE and not a JDK. I figured if I precompile the jsps, and put the resulting classfiles on the classpath, there should be no need for jetty to try and compile the jsp when the browser requests it, yet I get

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invoking javac. 
A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

no matter what I do when I request the jsp from the browser.

I have these init params in my webdefault.xml and the built class files are definitely on the classpath

```
   <init-param>
        <param-name>reloading</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>development</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>classpath</param-name>
        <param-value>c:/project/build/classes</param-value>
   </init-param>
```

How do I get jetty to not try and compile the jsp again so I can run it with a jre and not a jdk?

Comment: Maybe they have to be compiled to use some jetty specific stuff.  Different servlet containers use different ways of implementing the APIs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735628/precompile-jsps-into-classes-for-jetty8-using-ant

Comment: well  I compiled it with the same jspc class that jetty itself uses. What else could be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After wrestling with precompiling JSPs for Jetty running on a JRE I found that precompilation isn't necessary.  Jetty (7.5.5 and later) ships with a compiler that can be used to compile JSPs when Jetty is run using a JRE.  The details can be found on this page:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_JSP#Compiling_JSPs

In short, either add the following snippet to `jetty.xml`:

```xml
<Call class="java.lang.System"  name="setProperty">
  <Arg>org.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199</Arg>
  <Arg>true</Arg>
</Call>
```

or this line into `start.ini`:

```
-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.disablejsr199=true
```

Comment: I eventually figured that out too (I hadn't included the  org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.7.1.jar where the compiler is, so it took me a while to get it going. The problem I have now is that on android jetty doesn't work because even if you got it to compile, there's nothing to convert it to dalvik. So again precompiled jsps would be the way to go, but jetty refuses to pick them up.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the mappings aren't correct in web.xml - those are what sends the requests for the jsps to the compiled code.  Ultimately what you're trying to do is nothing more than mapping a pattern to a servlet. Try manually creating an entry in web.xml that maps an endpoint (e.g. /test) to the class created by JspC.  I'd tinker with an empty webapp to eliminate the possibility there's something else going on in the code.